# Preview website doesn't work in virtualmin on nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, preview, virtualmin

I've just installed virtualmin on nginx (I wanted ISPconfig on nginx, but I didn't succeeded). OS is Centos 6.4.
Since DNS didn't propagate I want to preview a website I've created, through Virtualmin->Services->Preview Website . First it worked, but after I've added the following lines on /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file it didn't worked anymore.

```
    fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

# enforce NO www
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
{
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
}

# unless the request is for a valid file, send to bootstrap
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

The code above is need  for making work permalinks on wordpress website.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure since I am not an expert, but, as per the [official documentation](https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/nginx),

> Nginx does not support CGI, so any applications or Virtualmin scripts that use CGI will not work. Virtualmin should prevent the installation of scripts that require CGI, mod_perl or Apache-specific features.

And when I try to preview a website, it redirects to:

https ://MYHOSTNAME:10000/virtual-server/**link.cgi**/MYHOSTNAME/http ://website

So it would be actually a broken feature when using nginx in virtualmin, I guess.